# Bash: how to create mapping using for loop?

Tags: bash, dictionary, mapping

I'm trying to create something similar to the dictionary in bash.

I mean similar to `data = {"hostname1": <ip_address1>, "hostname2": <ip_address2>}`.

Currently, I have the code like this:

```
for hostname in ${hostnames[@]}; do
    # Doing something.
    hostname_ip +=`(echo $var|xargs)`
done
```

And then I'm working with hostnames:

```
for the hostname in $hostnames; do
    # Doing something with `hostname`.
    Also, for some reason, I need the IP address for exact host here.
    But I have no idea how to extract it properly in bash...
```

Maybe mapping is not the best idea in bash, but I don't have better ideas...

Comment: Since version 4, bash supports associative arrays, which do exactly this. I think the syntax is horrible, but if you insist, check them out here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html

Comment: I'm trying to find something similar for bash3.

Comment: Couldn't you combine your two loops into one? `for hostname in ...; do body of 1st loop; body of 2nd loop; done`. That way you wouldn't run into the mapping problem. Alternatively, use two arrays, one for hostnames and one for their IPs. Instead of iterating over one of these array, iterate over their indices. The IP of `hostname[i]` would then be `ip[i]`.